# querying a table with multiple arrays with same name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using standard SQL in BigQuery trying to query a large table with multiple arrays. Several of the arrays were given the same name by whoever made the table. For example, there's `price` and `items.price` (arrays in arrays!). I'm trying to get at values inside of `price`, but it's telling me `price` is ambiguous when I try to `unnest`, I'm assuming because of `items.price`.

I've been researching this for a day and haven't been able to find a single resource that gives me any ideas. Here's my query:

```
SELECT timestamp, user_id, order_id, p.order_amount, i.quantity
FROM `transactions`,
 UNNEST(items) AS i, UNNEST(price) as p
```

I'm getting the following error: `Column name price is ambiguous`

Comment: `UNNEST(transactions.price)`

Comment: I tried this yesterday--sorry I forgot to mention that! It didn't work either. Given your idea, I also just tried SELECT * FROM transactions AS T as a subquery and then unnesting T.price, but that also said price was ambiguous within T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it's telling me price is ambiguous when I try to unnest

You need to reference it as a `t.price` instead of just `price`

```
SELECT timestamp, user_id, order_id, p.order_amount, i.quantity
FROM `transactions` t,
UNNEST(items) AS i, UNNEST(t.price) as p
```

Comment: There are two different prices: price (an array with multiple columns, from which I want to unnest a column value) and items.price (an array in an array, which I don't care about but I think is causing the ambiguity for the other price array). I did try to UNNEST i.price just to see if it would work and it's still giving me the error that price is ambiguous.

Comment: so you need price that is not the items.price? i thought opposite. please confirm. btw, hard to believe that using i.price still gives you ambiguity error! you might be doing something else? extra columns in select statement rather than those in your question

Comment: anyway - see updated answer - so now it will take price from root - not from items. looks like this is what you need

Comment: That did it. You're amazing! Thank you!